# How can I lock a limited access user from changing their own password in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, user, limited-user-account

My son needs to be logged into his own account but we restrict his usage by logging him in with a PW he doesn't know. He figured out he can change his password negating our control.

*Is it possible to lock his ability to change his own password?*

Answer (score 3):

If you are running a Home edition of Windows 7 and therefore cannot access the Local Users and Groups management console, you can achieve the same effect using the command line tool `net user`.

Open a elevated command prompt (right-click on the command prompt under the start menu and choose `Run as Administrator`), then run

```
net user UserAccountName /passwordchg:no
```

This will prevent the user from changing their password.

Answer (score 1):

This works in XP Pro, not sure that it works in all versions of Windows 7, but if you right click on My Computer, choose Manage, go to Local Users -> Users, right click on his account and hit properties, there's a check box for "User cannot change password"

It's worth a try. Obviously his account should not be a Administrator one if you don't want him changing this back.

Answer (score 1):

Open the start menu and right-click on "Computer", and select "Manage". If your account isn't an administrator, you may have to provide administrator credentials.

[image: Right-click menu]

In the Computer Management window, expand "Local Users and Groups" on the left, and click on "Users".

On your son's user account, right-click and select "Properties".

In the properties window, select "User cannot change password" and "Password never expires".

[image: computer management window]

*Click for a big version!*

Click okay and close the windows, you're done! Your son won't be able to change his password until that setting is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Run lusrmgr.msc
This will pull up local users and groups. Browse to users.
Select userid, right click select properties, check "user cannot change password" OK.

Comment: Does not work on Windows 7 Home versions, FYI.